# What are best practices for using IntPtr vs. void* in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli

I'm using it for passing native pointers between assemblies. It's unfortunate that strong typing goes out the window in that context. Or at least, I haven't figured out how to get cross-assembly access to a C++/CLI method that returns a pointer to a native UDT. So assuming I'm right that either `IntPtr` or `void*` is necessary here, which should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always prefer the [CLS-compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx) route, in this case `IntPtr`. Not all .NET languages know what `void*` is, but all know what `IntPtr` is.

Regarding cross-assembly use of native UDTs, see [`#pragma make_public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235607.aspx).

Comment: Make_public doesn't work for templates so I tend to just ignore its existence. :) Lots of my native UDTs are shared_ptrs of other UDTs!

The CLS compliance angle is interesting, but I'm exclusively using these pointers in my C++/CLI native code wrappers. It's entirely possible to pass the wrapper to a non-pointer language, but the non-pointer language won't ever need to use the pointer. It might however pass it back to C++/CLI in a different assembly. It makes me think that void* is a bit more explicit about where the pointer is intended for use.

Comment: Will using void* cause an error in any non-pointer languages?

Comment: @Matt Chambers : It will not be possible to call any method/property that takes or returns a `T*` from certain languages. Likewise, it's not possible to call any method/property that takes or returns an unsigned integral type other than `System::Byte` from certain languages. It's up to you whether or not you care about those languages.

Comment: @ildjarn: I actually _prefer_ to hide this particular method from every language except C++/CLI. I was originally using the internal access level but had to give that up when I started needing cross-assembly access. Is there an internal_except_for_cppcli access level that I don't know about? :)

Comment: @Matt Chambers : No, but if you control every assembly involved, then you can grant logical assembly-level `friend`ship using the [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). See this article specifically: [Friend Assemblies (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177208.aspx)

Comment: Nope, the assemblies actually belong to different libraries (I do control them both but I don't want to couple them so tightly). I'll call this one answered and maybe later ask a broader question; I suspect that having one or more C++/CLI wrapper assemblies be clients of another C++/CLI wrapper assembly can't be an uncommon requirement and it would be nice to hide the wrapped native pointers from non-C++/CLI code.